# Can we have tab bars in mobile browsers(Swipable)

Tags: website-design, user-expectation, accessibility, responsive-design, mobile-web

I have a website which has tab bars in the desktop version.
So when i make it responsive should i retain tabs or should i replace it with som other elements.
Mobile users tend to swipe to change bars on mobile but in browsers case it is not feasible to swipe , So what would be the alternate solution for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's 3 months since the post, so I'm curious to find out what you ended up going with.

I believe the core of your question is "how to deal with filters" on mobile. On Desktop, all options are visible, and when the user selects one, they get visual feedback as to which filter(tab) is being applied. Since you have multiple filters (in other words, it's not just one category), you might want to try something like [H&M](http://m2.hm.com/m/en_ca/men.genericdevice.html) does on their mobile site.

This example has three categories: 1.Category (type of clothing) 2.Filter (colour options, size etc) 3.Sort By (newest, price etc)

[image: h&m mobile - filter options]

When the user taps a filter (category/filter/sort by) a dropdown of links or fancy checkboxes slides down, along with a "apply filters" button. Once selected, A loading indicator tells us the selection is being applied, and next view is displayed.

Depending on how much info you have per filter, you can get away with     dropdowns for each filter. The key take-aways are **indicating the filter was applied** and **easy access to changing it**. You'll notice in the H&M example, the selected Category isn't visible until the user taps "Category" again, this is acceptable because they've witnessed a loader, and assume this new screen is what they chose. If it doesn't quite look right (they accidentally hit the wrong link) they already know where to tap to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen one website in which they have expanded menu but when you open it in mobile, the menu will get collapsed by well known "justified" icon. So I think this would be a good idea to convert the menu instead of listing all the menu in mobile screen.

Apart from this as we all know that its psychology of the mobile user that menu would be in collapse view so they definitely click on the icon of the menu to access it.
This is so simple concept so I would suggest you to go as per standard of the mobile app's concept.

Comment: It would be great if you can add some visuals to your answer :)  Thanks

Comment: Sure @jyo lemme give sometime to find examples

Comment: @jyo please refer www.creolestudios.com in web as well in mobile for example